# How to add custom class to get_avatar()

Tags: theme-development, comments, walker, gravatar

I am using a custom walker class to customize my comments section. It uses the following code to get the comment author image from gravatar

```
<?php if ( 0 != $args['avatar_size'] ) echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); ?>
```

The HTML output is as following

```
<img alt="" src="#" srcset="#" class="avatar avatar-60 photo" height="60" width="60">
```

I want to add a custom class to the `<img>` tag so the output will be like this

```
<img alt="" src="#" srcset="#" class="avatar avatar-60 photo myclass" height="60" width="60">
```

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_avatar()` function has many arguments, the last one is the interesting one, because you can pass additional classes, [also described in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar#.24args). So instead of

```
get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] );
```

you could use

```
get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'], '', '', array('class' => 'myclass') );
```